# Datediff more than 24 hours

Tags: sql

I have to datetimeoffset fields, which I want to calculate the time between then.

I have done this:

```sql
CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, P.DT_INIC_PARD , P.DT_TMNO_PARD ),0),114) AS 'Duration'.
```

The problem is: When the time between then is higher than 24 hours, the result query shows me '00:00'.

Example:

```
P.DT_INIC_PARD = 2014-03-18 07:00:00.0000000 -03:00

P.DT_TMNO_PARD = 2014-03-19 07:20:00.0000000 -03:00
```

This gives me more than 24 hours. And shows me '00:20'

The question is: how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you intend to do with that `DATEADD()` function?  What it's doing is turning your `DATEDIFF()` output into a `DATETIME` field, which you then `CONVERT()` to a time format.  You can't display more than 24 hours in a time format `00:00`, so you need to choose a different way to display the output.

This works fine:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2014-03-18 07:00:00.0000000' , '2014-03-19 07:20:00.0000000' ) -- 1460 minutes
```

If you want the result in days/hours/minutes you can use modulus division:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2014-03-18 07:00:00.0000000' , '2014-03-19 07:20:00.0000000') Duration)
SELECT CAST(Duration/1440 AS VARCHAR(15))+'d '
     + CAST((Duration-1440)/60 AS VARCHAR(15))+'h '
     + CAST((Duration-1440)%60 AS VARCHAR(15))+'m'
FROM cte
```

Comment: The way you did it dosen't work the way I'd like, but anyway, I used just the DATEDIFF to return in minutes and I treated the days in my C# backend. Thanks anyway! I cant give you a +1 cause I dont have reputation enough haha.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
SELECT  CAST(Duration/60 AS VARCHAR(5)) + ':' + 
        RIGHT('0'+ CAST(Duration % 60 AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
FROM (  SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, P.DT_INIC_PARD, P.DT_TMNO_PARD) Duration
        FROM YourTable) A
```

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a slightly different approach, works especially well for large time differences. The output is in the following format:

> HH:MM:SS

Of course that can be attempted by just removing/adding differing parts. Here is how it's done generically for one value:

```
DECLARE @NumberOfSeconds INT = 123

SELECT (CASE WHEN FLOOR(@NumberOfSeconds / (60 * 60)) < 10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END) + 
    CAST(FLOOR(@NumberOfSeconds / (60 * 60)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ':' + 
    (CASE WHEN FLOOR((@NumberOfSeconds % (60 * 60)) / 60) < 10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END) + 
    CAST(FLOOR((@NumberOfSeconds % (60 * 60)) / 60) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ':' + 
    (CASE WHEN FLOOR((@NumberOfSeconds % (60 * 60)) % 60) < 10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END) + 
    CAST(FLOOR((@NumberOfSeconds % (60 * 60)) % 60) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
```

And for this specific question:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(SECOND, DT_INIC_PARD, DT_TMNO_PARD) / (60 * 60)) < 10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END) + 
    CAST(FLOOR(DATEDIFF(SECOND, DT_INIC_PARD, DT_TMNO_PARD) / (60 * 60)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ':' + 
    (CASE WHEN FLOOR((DATEDIFF(SECOND, DT_INIC_PARD, DT_TMNO_PARD) % (60 * 60)) / 60) < 10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END) + 
    CAST(FLOOR((DATEDIFF(SECOND, DT_INIC_PARD, DT_TMNO_PARD) % (60 * 60)) / 60) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ':' + 
    (CASE WHEN FLOOR((DATEDIFF(SECOND, DT_INIC_PARD, DT_TMNO_PARD) % (60 * 60)) % 60) < 10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END) + 
    CAST(FLOOR((DATEDIFF(SECOND, DT_INIC_PARD, DT_TMNO_PARD) % (60 * 60)) % 60) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
FROM YourTable
```

As far as I can tell this works for as large of a time difference you have up to the max value of a "int".